# Putty / SSH: How do I get my command line back?

Tags: ssh, keyboard-shortcuts, putty

I am new to Putty and SSH.

When I submit an odd/wrong command or sometimes when I am using Vi, something strange happens and I cannot get the prompt back; it just looks like this:

[image: Putty Terminal]
How do I get back to the command line from there?

Answer (score 9):

Try to do the following:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>

That should unlock the current operation.

Comment: That was driving me crazy.